# Using tokio::time::timeout does not trap delayed response from TCPReadStream

Tags: rust, timeout, p2p, rust-tokio, handshake

I'm writing a PoC P2P node handshake to a BitCoin server.
I send a 'version' message to the target node and it responds with its corresponding version message.  So far so good.

However, every now and again, the version message from the target node can take over two minutes to arrive.  The server does eventually give a successful response, but since I have applied a 5 second timeout to other network activity, I thought that for consistency, I should do the same here.

Here's the code without any check for a timeout.  This works, albeit sometimes very slowly:

```rust
use bitcoin::{
    consensus::Decodable,
    p2p::message::{self},
};
use std::{
    io::BufReader,
    net::{IpAddr, SocketAddr, TcpStream},
    time::{Duration, SystemTime},
};

pub async fn handshake(to_address: IpAddr, port: u16, timeout: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let target_node = SocketAddr::new(to_address, port);

    let mut write_stream = TcpStream::connect_timeout(&target_node, Duration::from_secs(timeout))?;

    // Build and send version message
    send_msg_version(&target_node, &mut write_stream)?;

    let read_stream = write_stream.try_clone()?;
    let mut stream_reader = BufReader::new(read_stream);

    let response1 = message::RawNetworkMessage::consensus_decode(&mut stream_reader)?;

    match response1.payload() {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    // More stuff here...
}
```

The call to `consensus_decode()` is what sometimes takes a very long time, so I've tried wrapping it in a `future::ready()`, then placing that inside a call to `tokio::time::timeout()` like this:

```rust
    let response1 = if let Ok(net_msg) = tokio::time::timeout(
        Duration::from_secs(timeout),
        future::ready(message::RawNetworkMessage::consensus_decode(&mut stream_reader)?),
    )
    .await
    {
        net_msg
    } else {
        return Err(CustomError(format!(
            "TIMEOUT: {} failed to respond with VERSION message within {} seconds",
            to_address, timeout
        )));
    };
```

The `(&mut stream_reader)?` part successfully traps any decoding errors, yet if the message arrives successfully, but too slowly, the `tokio::time::timeout` isn't able to trap it.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `future::ready` to make a synchronous function call asynchronous, use `tokio::task::spawn_blocking` instead:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
fn takes_long() {
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let x = tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_millis(10), tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
        takes_long();
    })).await;
    eprintln!("{x:?}");
}
```

produces this output:

```
Err(Elapsed(()))
```

The problem with your approach is that before `future::ready` is called (let alone `tokio::time::timeout` which is called even later), the function `consensus_decode` must have already returned and produced a value, at which point the `future::ready` can immediately return and your timeout never triggers.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solution by @cafce25, which is especially useful if you want cancelled calculations to not occupy CPU time (which they do with @cafce25's solution), is to make `consensus_decode()` asynchronous and springle [`tokio::task::yield_now().await`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.yield_now.html) calls every now and then (for example, every loop iteration) in the `consensus_decode()` function.

A better (more performant) but unstable solution is to use [`tokio::task::consume_budget().await`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.consume_budget.html), but that requires [the `tokio_unstable` flag](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/#unstable-features).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  Unfortunately, the `consensus_decode()` function is part of the `bitcoin` crate, and (at this point in time at least) I do not intend to alter it's functionality  :-)

Comment: @ChrisW Fair enough. Then use `spawn_blocking()` as @cafce25 said.